# What would the indifference curve of min{√x,y} looks like?

Tags: utility

The locus of kinks would follow x=y^2 but what would the arms look like?

Comment: Consider $\min \{\sqrt{x},y\}=k$ for various values of $k$.

Comment: What have you tried to figure this out?

Comment: @Giskard I started with finding out the locus of the kinks by taking √x = y. Then I took y=k and √x = k to find the arms of the IC but I was confused about the √x = k arm. I thought that it will be a non - linear arm but the answer below by Amit clarifies the confusion

Answer (score 3):

This is how indifference curves look :
[image]